# get the selected value(entire object) using angular selectbox

Tags: angularjs

I am able to render the angular selectbox using the following JSON.

```
$scope.rejectionTypes = [  
   {  
      "code":"88",
      "description":"Other reasons",
      "type":{  
         "code":"PR",
         "description":"Permoanent Rejection"
      }
   },
   {  
      "code":"92",
      "description":"Bank Excluded",
      "type":{  
         "code":"OT",
         "description":"Non Financial Transactions"
      }
   }
]
```

### template

```
<select class="form-control" name="tranCode" data-ng-model="rowUnderEdit.rejectionReason" data-ng-change="populateRejectDesc(transactionType)">
    <option data-ng-repeat="transactionType in rejectionTypes" ng-selected="compareSelect(transactionType, rowUnderEdit.rejectionReason)" >{{transactionType.code}}-{{transactionType.description}}</option>
</select>
```

Problem is, whenever the option changes need to get the entire object from the 'transactionType' (i.e, code, description and type). Is there any way to get the entire object.

```
{  
          "code":"88",
          "description":"Other reasons",
          "type":{  
             "code":"PR",
             "description":"Permoanent Rejection"
          }
       }
```

I try to get it in the following way, but it is throwing: '**transactionType is undefined**'

```
data-ng-change="populateRejectDesc(transactionType)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select>` is meant to be used with `ng-options`.
Prepare a `label` in objects

```
$scope.rejectionTypes.map(function(item){
  item.label = item.code + '-' + item.description;
});
```

and display them like this

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in rejectionTypes" ng-model="selected">
```

The variable `selected` provided to `ng-model` will give control over the selected item. You can assign it in controller (`$scope.selected = $scope.rejectionTypes[0]`) and read it's value after it has been changed in UI
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B0iu17Iqzf1lXbjQTq99?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing that you want, I performed with the help of ng-options because when you are using ng-repeat with `<option>` then ng-model of `<select>` will contain 'string' value.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<select class="form-control" name="tranCode" data-ng-model="rowUnderEdit.rejectionReason" data-ng-change="populateRejectDesc(rowUnderEdit.rejectionReason)" data-ng-options="check(transactionType) for transactionType in rejectionTypes">

</select>
</div>
```

Angularjs:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.rejectionTypes = [  
   {  
      "code":"88",
      "description":"Other reasons",
      "type":{  
         "code":"PR",
         "description":"Permoanent Rejection"
      }
   },
   {  
      "code":"92",
      "description":"Bank Excluded",
      "type":{  
         "code":"OT",
         "description":"Non Financial Transactions"
      }
   }
];
    $scope.compareSelect=function(transactionType, rejectionReason){
       // $scope.selectedObject=transactionType;
        console.log(rejectionReason);
    };
    $scope.populateRejectDesc=function(transactionType){
        console.log('Object',transactionType);//your object
    }
    $scope.check=function(object){
      return object.code+'-'+object.description;
    }
});
```

Fiddle for solution:http://jsfiddle.net/y4dy1uqu/4/